# How to rotate the camera viewer in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, windows-phone-7.1

I use `PhotoCamera` option to take the snapshot. Once the Image capture is completed i set the `VideoBrush` to the Canvas in xaml. But the video viewer is actually rotated than the original... .I am not sure what might be the problem..

My code..

```
myCamera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);

myCamera.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<ContentReadyEventArgs>(CameraCaptureImageAvailable);

VideoBrush videobrush = new VideoBrush();
videobrush.SetSource(myCamera);
canvasCameraView.Background = videobrush;
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612562/viewfinder-orientation-with-windows-phone-7-mango-photocamera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution that we can achieve through CompositeTransform...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx